# radtest no response from outside localhost

Tags: ubuntu, vps, azure, radius, freeradius

I have set up freeradius in a Microsoft Azure VM. When I `radtest` from `127.0.0.1`, it sends Access-Accept. But when I run `radtest` from another computer, freeradius doesn't respond. I am running freeradius in debug mode to see any debug output.
I have assigned a public IP to my VM. When I run `radtest john testpassword x.x.x.x 0 testing123` (where `x.x.x.x` is my public IP) from other machine other than the VM running freeradius, no response from server.
I have also enabled endpoints in Azure portal to allow port 1812 and 1813 publicly.
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with freeradius v2.2.9 and radiusdesk with nginx

Endpoint configuration:

[image: endpoint setup]

Comment: Show the endpoints you have configured in Azure.

Comment: http://i66.tinypic.com/2qd0iuf.jpg

Comment: This is my endpoint configuration

Comment: Please *edit your question* with additional info; don't embed it in comments, especially with links to images which are easily changed to be viewable in the question itself. I am editing your question to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RADIUS uses UDP ports, but you have not opened UDP ports in your endpoint configuration. Once you fix the endpoint configuration to open the correct ports, you should be able to communicate with the FreeRADIUS server.

Comment: Thanks. Adding UDP endpoints solved the problems. I just created two more endpoints with UDP 1812 and 1813. You saved my day